# How to automatically delete old Azure Blob Storage containers

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Microsoft offers the Lifecycle Management service, which allows me to setup a rule for an action.

There, I can delete old blobs by setting up an expiration date. However, after deleting all the blobs the container remains there, forever empty.

Is there any configuration that also deletes de container whenever it is x days old and/or empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don’t have container delete as part of life-cycle management now.We are in planning to add in the future.

You can share your feedback or suggestion [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage). All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Comment: Hello @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT, do you have any idea when this feature will be available?

Comment: Voted here [Please add life cycle management policy at the container level as well](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f2d34b29-3925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0f84)