# Azure lifecycle policy for container is not working

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have configured azure lifecycle policy for container as below,

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "name",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "storageaccount/container"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So it will delete the blobs which was modified before 30 days. I am putting backups in the container so I want to delete the old backups which is 30 days older.

I configured this policy before 2 days before. Yet old backup files are not removed from the container

I analyzed and as per below links after the new policy configuration it will take up 24 hrs to take effect for new policy and policy update

ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview?tabs=azure-portal#faq

[Lifecycle management policy not working on Azure Data Lake Gen 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167364/lifecycle-management-policy-not-working-on-azure-data-lake-gen-2)

I cant find many documents regarding this issue also

I configured Firewalls and virtual networks as 'all networks'. why i am mention this because according to below documents his solution works,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/107954/lifecycle-mangement-isn39t-doing-anything.html

Yet there is no update in containers. So anyone know the reason and troubleshoots to resolve this?
thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Please check if below points can help:

**Things to check:**

1. Please check if there any [immutability policies configured for blob
   versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-portal#enable-version-level-immutability-for-a-new-container) .

> If version-level immutability support is enabled for a container and
> the container contains one or more blobs, then you must delete all
> blobs in the container before you can delete the container, even if
> there are no immutability policies in effect for the container or its
> blobs.

2. Please check if [last access time tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview?tabs=azure-portal#:%7E:text=turn%20off%20last%20access%20time%20tracking.) is enabled, because
   every time the blobs are accessed they move to hot tier and may
   change its modified time. You need to make sure you are using a V2
   storage account: [optionally-enable-access-time-tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal#optionally-enable-access-time-tracking)

**Work around :**

Use  **az cli** to add life cycle policy to delete the blobs in the container whose last modification time is more than 30 days.

Note: (Try **simply specifying the container name** as blob prefixcontainer name in prefixmatch instead of storageaccount/container)

*Ex policy.json :*

```
 "rules": [
    {
      "name": "expirationRule1",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ],
          "prefixMatch": [ "containername" ]
        },
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 30 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Try to create this lifecycle management policy (policy.son) using the [az cli command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/management-policy?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_management_policy_create):

```
az storage account management-policy create --account-name youraccountname --policy @policy.json --resource-group myresourcegroup
```

**References:**

1. [lifecycle - Unable to add new rule in Storage Management Policy on
   Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468824/unable-to-add-new-rule-in-storage-management-policy-on-azure)
2. [How to automatically delete old Azure Blob Storage containers -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987417/how-to-automatically-delete-old-azure-blob-storage-containers?rq=1)

Comment: Your analysis is Really helpful for some aspects. Thanks for such a great points! I just figured out the error on the same day the question posted and rectified. But i liked your comment when i read it and upvoted it for your effort. keep this work! again thanks!

Comment: @jayaprakashR What was the fault in your configuration ? I also am seeing this problem and can't figure out why my lifecycle policy isn't deleting blobs